# Should I use react-google-maps or inject google-map in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am rendering Poly-lines, Polygons, and Markers in react-google-map with react and all data-sets are independent so one of them updates all others are updated that is unnecessary.
My question is should I use react-google-maps or directly inject google-maps so I can only update the changed data like if Poly-lines are updated it should only update the Poly-lines not everything.
Or does react-google-maps takes care of the rendering. does it only renders the updated data because I don't think its only updated the changed data it re-renders it all.

I tried both and with react-google-maps, I don't have to use componentWillRecieveProps to render data on map.

I expect to render only the changed layer data.

Comment: I think there is no simple direct answer to your question. If you build around google map API, you don't need to worry about upgrading react or any breaking changes.

`render only the changed layer data`, if you do by your self detecting what is changed may go difficult.

Comment: if I build around google map API you mean `react-google-maps` library or my own wrapper where I inject script or something.

Comment: No, I mean google map javascript API